Overriding Save but database is not updated
I have a model, containing a save overide, that uses a function to set whether a sync is required based on a comparison of dates.   The save is called by update_or_create which is in turn called by a management command
For the purposes of debugging this issue sync_required is set to True regardless.
class Site(models.Model):

# LastEditDate & LastEditTime
LastEditDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
LastEditTime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
...

# System Specific
date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
last_synced = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
sync_required = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=True, default=False)

# Function to calculate if sync required.
def is_sync_required(self):
    ...
    return True

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.sync_required = self.is_sync_required()
    logger.info(
        f"Site/Save: LED:{self.LastEditDate}, LET:{self.LastEditTime}, DM:{self.date_modified}, LS:{self.last_synced} = SR:{self.sync_required}")
    super(Site, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

The is_sync_required method produces the correct output when used in full:
A001
Site/is_sync_required/Return for A001= True with MinutesSince>=0 84659.0
Site/Save: LED:2024-02-29, LET:09:06:04.174000, DM:2024-09-27 08:19:27.430154+00:00, LS:2024-01-01 14:06:28+00:00 = SR:True

A002
Site/is_sync_required/Return for A002= False with MinutesSince<0 -25449.0
Site/Save: LED:2024-08-14, LET:16:51:17.732000, DM:2024-09-27 08:20:33.720193+00:00, LS:2024-09-01 08:00:00+00:00 = SR:False

A003
Site/is_sync_required/Return for A003= True with last_synced_none None
Site/Save: LED:2024-09-02, LET:08:25:50.232000, DM:2024-09-27 08:18:35.456365+00:00, LS:None = SR:True

A004
Site/is_sync_required/Return for A004= True with MinutesSince>=0 51517.0
Site/Save: LED:2024-08-06, LET:09:43:40.257000, DM:2024-09-27 08:21:40.917783+00:00, LS:2024-07-01 14:06:28+00:00 = SR:True

However, the result of sync_required is not being saved to the database.  Looking at other questions/answers the save override method is correct so I'm left considering issues with caching and foreign keys.

Django - Save override to update fields issue seems to relate to interactions with other tables.
Django - Query on overridden save() method cached or something

The model does not have any Foreign Key references of its own (i.e. is not a Child) but is referenced by another model (i.e. is a Parent).   Does that mean its save is being overwritten by its children?
I have considered the following:

If you wish to update a field value in the save() method, you may also want to have this field added to the update_fields keyword argument. This will ensure the field is saved when update_fields is specified. For example:

    if (
        update_fields := kwargs.get("update_fields")
    ) is not None and "sync_required" in update_fields:
        kwargs["update_fields"] = {"sync_required"}.union(update_fields)

but this didn't fix the issue.
UPDATE
Test: Here I tested the save override in isolation from the update_or_create method where updates the DB as expected:
def test_sync_required(self, site_id):
    site = Site.objects.get(site_id=site_id)
    print(f"BEFORE: {site.site_id} @ {site.date_modified} = {site.sync_required}")
    site.save()
    print(f"AFTER: {site.site_id} @ {site.date_modified} = {site.sync_required}")

Results in:
BEFORE: A0001 @ 2024-09-27 10:15:52.541122+00:00 = False
AFTER: A0001 @ 2024-09-27 10:16:18.717731+00:00 = True

Solution:   This doesn't seem like a nice solution because I'm saving the object twice and can't just automatically trust that sync_required will be updated on every save but I have taken the obect returned by the update_or_create, called is_sync_required on it and then added an additional save.
# update or create the site based on whether it already exists.
local_site, created = Site.objects.update_or_create(...)

# Call the local site is_sync_required model method and then save.
local_site.is_sync_required()
local_site.save()

I believe this behaviour to be linked with this discussion on update_or_create Behavior.
